# Can a Covariance-Stationary series be Heteroskedastic?

Tags: time-series, arima, covariance, heteroscedasticity, stationarity

Can a time series that satisfies the covariance-stationary properties (mean of x(t) and covariance between x(t) and x(t+m) are both constant relative to t) be heteroskedastic (variance of x(t) changes with respect to t)?

Comment: No but the conditional variance can be time-varying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You're asking for $\text{cov}(X_t,X_{t+m})$ to not depend on $t$, only on $m$, for all integers $m$. In particular, for $m=0$:

$$\text{cov}(X_t,X_{t+0}) = \text{cov}(X_t,X_t) = \text{var}(X_t)$$

So, the variance can't depend on $t$ either, that's included in the restrictions on the autocovariance function.

Edit: I suppose I didn't anticipate the confusion behind the question as the others did, but they are correct: the variance of the transition distribution (or conditional distribution) can depend on $t$ and still be stationary, as in a (stationary) GARCH model.

That distinction applies to the mean as well, and is maybe simpler to understand there. Take $X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$, with $|\phi|<1$, which is stationary. The mean $E(X_t)=0$ doesn't depend on $t$, but the transition distribution is $X_t|X_{t-1} \sim \mathcal{N}(\phi X_{t-1},\sigma^2)$, so does depend on $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers that I have seen so far are correct: The **unconditional** variance of a (covariance-) stationary process does not depend on the point in time. However, the **conditional** variance (to which you might be refering to) *may* depend on the past of the process.

You might want to check out [Conditonally Heteroskedastic Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity). Autoregressive Moving Average models are used to model the conditional mean of a time series while GARCH models are used to describe the conditional variance of a time series.